# In Law vs Doflamingo, why didn't Law swap Doflamingo's soul?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, Law can easily swap two people's soul, but he didn't use it when fighting with Doflamingo. Let's say if he swapped Nami and Doflamingo's soul, it would so easy for him to defeat him that way.

Why didn't Law swap Doflamingo's soul to make the fight easier?

Comment: Looks like the "swap soul" ability can only be done inside the ROOM? Which mean [In Law vs Doflamingo, why didn't Law use ROOM?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13536/in-law-vs-doflamingo-why-didnt-law-use-room?noredirect=1&lq=1) should be related or even possibly a duplicate.

Comment: The link only shows slicing part and for shambles he do not need to actually hit, from what i remember when he used it on straw hats he switched them standing at one place and just using his 2 fingers.

Answer (score 2):

In Chapter 690 of the manga, Law is facing off against Vergo, while at the same time talking to Doflamingo. When Vergo shows off his full body Armament Haki, Doflamingo states to Law that "Even your severing powers can do nothing to the strength of his Haki!"

This strongly implies that Armament Haki is able to offer some level of resistance against the effects of certain Devil Fruit powers, Law's being one of them. It is reasonable to assume that Doflamingo's proficiency with Haki is better than Law's, therefore he had increased resistance against Law's powers, such as the soul-switching ability.

Comment: Man yes u r correct, obviously haki - why didnot i think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say he swaps Nami and Doffy.
Who should they kill then doffy's soul or his body?

Wouldn't doffy just kill nami? As, if you have seen in Punk Hazard. People who's body's/soul's get switched tend to get full control over the other persons body.
Remeber Sanji touching nami's stuff. That's just a suicidal idea to be honest. Because doffy's personality is next level. He wouldn't hesitate before killing anyone. 
Plus Luffy always wants a fair fight. Definitely not his style he would never agree.

Comment: If mingo killed nami his conciousness leave earth then so hecant kill nami and then he becomes weak they can just use sea stone to bind mingo and reswap them . I mean luffy wants fair fight but he cant stop law from doing that .